# Determine the Steady State Temperature of the Sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the unit sphere with surface temperature determined by the following equation in Cartesian coordinates:

$$u(x,y,z)=x^2+2y^2+3z^2$$

The general solution for the Laplacian in spherical coordinates is given by

$$\sum_{l=o}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-l}^l C_{l,m}\rho^l P_l^m(\cos\theta)e^{im\phi}$$

where $P_l^m$ denotes the associated Legendre polynomial.

We start by rewriting the boundary condition in terms of spherical coordinates, noting the $\rho=1$ at the surface, since this is a unit sphere. Then we have

$$\sin^2{\theta}\cos^2{\phi}+2\sin^2{\theta}\sin^2{\phi}+3\cos^2{\theta}$$
$$\rightarrow \sin^2{\theta}(\cos^2{\phi}+2\sin^2{\phi})+3\cos^2{\theta}$$
$$\rightarrow \sin^2{\theta}(1+\sin^2{\phi})+3\cos^2{\theta}$$

The possible associated Legendre polynomials we could use are:

\begin{align}
P_0^0(\cos\theta)&=1\\
P_0^1(\cos\theta)&=\cos\theta\\
P_1^1(\cos\theta)&=-\sin\theta\\
P_0^2(\cos\theta)&=\frac{1}{2}(3\cos^2\theta-1)\\
P_1^2(\cos\theta)&=-3\cos\theta\sin\theta\\
P_2^2(\cos\theta)&=3\sin^2\theta\\
\end{align}

No matter what I do I can't seem to get a form where the trig functions agree with each other. Maybe it has something to do with only considering the imaginary part? I'm also unsure if I could simultaneously consider imaginary parts and real part for the same solution. Thoughts?

Comment: How is $u$ related to the question? Could you clarify what you are looking for since your post is not very clear?

Comment: It's the surface temperature of the unit sphere. Or you could imagine it's the potential of the unit sphere. The value inside the sphere will be completely determined by the surface value. The Lagrange's equation is used to do this.

Comment: First, note that
\begin{align}
\sin^2{\theta}(1+\sin^2{\phi})+3\cos^2{\theta}=&\ 1+\sin^2\phi+(2-\sin^2\phi)\cos^2\theta\\
=&\ 1+\sin^2\phi+\frac{1}{3}(2-\sin^2\phi)+(2-\sin^2\phi)(\cos^2\theta-\frac{1}{3})\\
=&\ \frac{5}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\sin^2\phi+\frac{2}{3}(2-\sin^2\phi)P^2_0(\cos\theta)
\end{align}